# How to use Blocks.Count<TSource>() in a WPF RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, iqueryable

In a WPF `RichTextBox` I need to count all blocks of type `Paragraph`. Intellisense offers the `Count<TSource>()` method.

[image]

But using it this way:

```
int paragraphNumber = this.Document.Blocks.Count<Paragraph>();
```

I get the compile error CS1929 which states that BlockCollection does not contain any definition for "count".

Where am I wrong?

Comment: `int paragraphNumber = Document.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>().Count();`

Comment: @Clemens Yes, of course, you are right. But that does not correspond to the Intellisense text, right?

Comment: The IntelliSense shows very clearly that the expected parameter type for the `Count<TSource>()` extension method is `IEnumerable<Block>()`. If you explicitly provide the type parameter, and set it to `Paragraph`, then you are trying to call a method having the signature `int Count<Paragraph>(IEnumerable<Paragraph>)` but passing it parameter of type `IEnumerable<Block>`, since the `Blocks` has the type `TextElementCollection<Block>` and so implements only `IEnumerable<Block>` and (importantly) **not** `IEnumerable<Paragraph>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `Count()` expects is the type of your source collection items. In your case this would be the type `Block` as you are dealing with a `BlockCollection`. This type can usually be inferred from usage and be omitted, but you can't use that as a filtering method.

You can do it like this:

```
int paragraphNumber = this.Document.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>().Count();
```

Or with a lambda expression:

```
int paragraphNumber = this.Document.Blocks.Count(x => x is Paragraph);
```

Comment: But that does not correspond to the Intellisense text, right? Or how should I understand the <TSource>?

Comment: I edited my answer with a litte bit more explanation. The IntelliSense text only tells you to provide the type of the items in your collection (which also can be left out) and can't be used as a filter.